# upgrade to SQL Server 2016 from 2012 SP3 have 2 components failing

Tags: sql-server, ssms-2016

upgrade to SQL Server 2016 from 2012 SP3 have 2 components failing "Client Tools SDK" and "Client Tools Backward Compatibility" are they necessary on the server or just client side? or is there a magic trick to getting them to upgrade? i've googled myself silly and tried everything i could find to no avail.  i'd really like to get this upgraded but unless i can get these 2 components upgraded i'm stuck on 2012 until the end of time...thanks in advance!

Comment: what does the error log say ?

Comment: that's the problem...it says nothing at all for a corrective action that was the first thing i checked

Comment: Detailed results:
  Feature:                       Client Tools SDK
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  Reason for failure:            An error occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail.
  Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.

Comment: why not just remove the old versions, before upgrade, then at a later time add them after the upgrade? I have never had the need for the SDK on the server.

Comment: @Ricardo i'm new to SQL Server in general and if i can leave those 2 components off of the server i'd prefer to at this point. i'm just unsure as to whether they **need** to be there

Comment: well, I would still try a removal first, as i suggested. also, inspect the windows logs for a description of the error.

Comment: I'll give that a shot Ricardo.  hopefully they are unnecessary & i can remove them permanently

Comment: You can try to update to 2014 and after to 2016...